# Como fazer um evento ser executado somente quando o mouse for pressionado

Tags: vb.net

Olá. Eu gostaria de saber se em VB.NET (Windows forms) tem como fazer um evento acontecer somente durante o tempo em que o botão do mouse (LMB) é pressionado.

Por exemplo, enquanto o usuário segurar o botão do mouse, a tecla "W" ficará sendo enviada diversas vezes. E assim que ele soltar o botão do mouse, a tecla "W" irá parar de ser enviada.

E também, se tem como fazer isso funcionar em segundo plano, no caso, não só dentro do programa, mas em todo o computador, usando a função press por exemplo, só que isso seria mais uma função "hold" , um exemplo de código:

```
If Held.Keys.LMB = True
    SendKeys.Send("W")
End If
```

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Onde pretende que esse código seja executado? No próprio _form_? Tem os eventos _MouseDown_ e _MouseUp_ para esse efeito.

Answer (score 0):

A solução mais rápida que pode ser feita é com a função `GetAsyncKeyState` usando um Timer.

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vKey As Long) As Integer

' Esse valor é dado em milissegundos, define o tempo
' que o timer irá verificar se o botão do mouse está sendo pressionado
' e se estiver, irá chamar o evento
' Obs.: valores mais baixos influenciam numa perda de performance drástica
Public Const TempoResposta As Integer = 500

Public WithEvents Timer1 As New Timer

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Timer1.Interval = TempoResposta
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Timer() Handles Timer1.Tick
    ' Botão esquerdo do mouse
    If GetAsyncKeyState(1) = 0 Then
         SendKeys.Send("W")
    End If

'    ' Botão direito do mouse
'    If GetAsyncKeyState(2) = 0 Then
'        ' está sendo pressionado
'    Else
'        ' foi soltado
'    End If
End Sub
```

No código, já foi declarado um Timer com eventos. Você pode usar um que já foi usado no Designer, é só substituir os nomes.

---

[Fonte do código.](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?852299-RESOLVED-How-to-Detect-Mouse-Click-Outside-of-Form)

[Fonte do código 2.](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29726/Detect-System-Wide-Mouse-Events)

[Documentação do GetAsyncKeyState.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/ms646293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)